# Customer token amount not shown in Metamask

Tags: metamask

I deploy standard ERC20 test token called BEERS ( by copy and paste the standard ERC20 code ) onto Rinkeby network.

Then I transferred some BEERS token to my Metamask account[0] through Remix. I can confirm the result in Remix that my Metamask account[0] now has some BEERS.

Then I tried to claim the custom token in Metamask, it recognised the Token Contract Address with Token Symbol and Decimal automatically, but it shows I have 0 BEERS.

I can't figure out why... any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be possible that you transferred 1 or 2 BEERS which might have been evaluated as `0.000000000000000001` or `0.000000000000000002` BEERS

Comment: Do you have the source of the contract? What is the transaction id? Often wallets use Transfer events to recognize tokens. If your transaction failed the event will not be generated, also it might be your contract doesn't generate a Transfer event.